# calling a class's non-static member from another class's static member

Tags: c++

I have two classes;

encoder.h

```cpp
#include "stationControl.h"

    public:
         static void getLocation();
         static stationControl *station1;
         static stationControl *station2;
         static stationControl *station3;
    private:
         static stationControl *stations[3];
```

encoder.cpp

```cpp
#include "encoder.h"

stationControl *encoder::station1;
stationControl *encoder::station2;
stationControl *encoder::station3;

stationControl *encoder::stations[] = {encoder::station1,encoder::station2,encoder::station3};

void encoder::getLocation()
{
  *stations[1]->*stationControl::senarioControl(); // Here is the problematic line
}
```

stationControl.h

```cpp
   public:      
      void (stationControl::*senarioControl)();
      void controlOut();
```

stationControl.cpp

```cpp
#include "stationControl.h"

stationControl::stationControl()
{   
    senarioControl= &stationControl::controlOut;
}

void stationControl::controlOut()
{
     // some staffs...
}
```

- I need static stationControl object in encoder.h
- I need non-static controlOut function for every stationControl object (every function is special for its object)
- I need to create a pointer for controlOut function as senarioControl
- I need to call senarioControl pointer from encoder::getLocation

As on the code above in encoder.cpp (signed with "// Here is the problematic line" ), I got an error like;

```
invalid use of member 'stationControl::senarioControl' in static member function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`senarioControl` is a member of `stations[1]`, so you access it, like all members, as

```
stations[1]->senarioControl
```

Then you dereference it relative to `stations[1]`, remembering that you need parentheses:

```
stations[1]->*(stations[1]->senarioControl)
```

Then you call the function, and due to precedence rules you need another pair of parentheses:

```
(stations[1]->*(stations[1]->senarioControl))();
```

This is so unreadable that it's common to add another member that only calls through the function pointer:

```
class stationControl
{
    public:
        void callScenario() { (this->*senarioControl)(); }
        ...
```

so you can write the much more readable

```
stations[1]->callScenario();
```